# Jrating and multiple ratings

Tags: jquery, rating

I am trying to set up a rating solution. I think I will use Jrating (http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jrating).

I just want to be sure if it is possible to have multiples ratings in one form ? Because I have a form with 5 differents rates.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Even though you use it inside a `<form>` it's no different from the different ratings on the [demo page](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/).

Most UI libraries will allow you to create multiple elements that are independent of each other.

A brief look at jRating suggests that it does not use form elements directly - i.e. you need to put code into the `onSuccess` handler to send the data to the server. (For example by setting the value of a hidden input element.) Since you have to do this yourself the library won't cause any conflicts with duplicate `name` values for input fields.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand correctly what you said. What I need to do is to send the result of the rating to a hidden input. To do so I can use the onSucces() method. Then I send my form and I can save the result in my database.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple ratings on the demo page: http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jrating/
I will go on a limb and say yes you can have multiple ratings.